# How to use ifstream to open a .tab file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I did try searching but to no avail. I have working code that can open the input file I tell it to. It only works on .txt files. I need it to be able to open and eventually display a .tab file. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Lexer.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string fname, line;
    ifstream ifs; // input file stream
    int i;

    Token tok; Lexer lexer;
    cout << "Enter a file to open" << endl;
    while (getline(cin, fname)) // Ctrl-Z/D to quit!
    { 
        ifs.open(fname.c_str(), ios::binary);
        if (ifs.fail()) 
        {
            cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open file " << fname << endl;
            ifs.clear();
        } 
        else 
        {
            while (getline(ifs, line)) 
            {
                cout << line << endl;
            }
            ifs.close();
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you display some of your code please?  It would help to determine what you are missing.

Comment: make sure you open the file in binary mode if it's not a plaintext file.

Comment: Hmmm, `iOS::binary`? Perhaps you meant `ios::binary`?

Comment: It is is ios::binary in my code, autocorrect changed it to iOS.

Comment: @JimGorski: Most likely the file name typed on the prompt doesn't match the actual filename (or path). Please show us what the filepath is and what you type in.

Comment: I have a file named test.txt and a test.tab in the same folder as the .cpp file I'm compiling. the test.txt file opens, the test.tab couts the error message.

Comment: I just tested the code here and it works fine. You are making a trivial error somewhere.

Comment: If only the filename is being entered then it must be in the same directory as that in which the program is running. The fact that it is in the same directory as the `.cpp` is irrelevant. Are there two `test.txt` files on file system in different directories? Where do you execute the program from?

Comment: I am having this same problem. Looking into "Formatted Text file" rather than just text file. Did you get this to work?